# python error for multiplication

Tags: python

I am creating a multiplication program, here is the code for the multiplying:

```
 def multiply():
    print('enter two numbers in this format (x, y)')
    mult = input()
    multy = list(mult)
    answer = multy[1] * multy[2]
    print(answer)
```

and here is my error:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/math clac.py", line 36, in <module>
    multiply()
  File "C:/Python34/math clac.py", line 17, in multiply
    answr = multy[1] * multy[2]
IndexError: list index out of range`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Lists in python are `0` based. If you enter two elements, the list has elements in the indexes `multy[0]` and `multy[1]`, not `multy[1]` and `multy[2]`. When you try and access `multy[2]` python *tells you* that: **list index out of range**.

Comment: ohhh duuhh, brain fart on my part, sorry all, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def multiply():
    print('enter two numbers in this format (x, y)')
    mult = input()
    multy = list(mult)
    answer = multy[0] * multy[1]
    print(answer)
```

Where the indices are 0 and 1, rather than 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way also

```
def multiply():
    print('enter two numbers in this format (x, y)')
    mult = input()
    multy = list(mult)

    #the second item in list will be space or either your delimeter
    #in python list index always start with 0, this follow the other programming language also
    answer = int(multy[0]) * int(multy[2])
    print(answer)


multiply()
```

Output

```
enter two numbers in this format (x, y)
1,2

2

enter two numbers in this format (x, y)
7,7

49
```